# latency during upsert activity through azure data factory

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-sql-database, latency, upsert

I want to know the **latency** that data factory gives when I runs an upsert activity. The scenario is that i have heavy data that I have to update and insert daily from on premise to Azure SQL database, the new data should sort incrementally & inserts in the desired place.
Example. I have Alphabetical data in which B is missing and new data contains B so it should automatically inserts in between A and C.
What will be the latency during 500 GB if data upsertion.

Comment: SQL Azure's performance depends on what resource tier you use.  Please specify that if you want help/guidance

Comment: lets take an organisational billing Azure account with ~400 DTUs

Comment: I suggest you look at the vcore model as it is more explicit in giving you latency and IOPS so you can do estimation activites like what you appear to be doing here.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-vcore-resource-limits-single-databases

Comment: 500 gb, looks a lot. what is an estimated number of rows? I would create an SP (MERGE logic) in Azure SQL Db and process the data in batches from the staging table.